# Convert .Net int array to Java.Lang.Object

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin, xamarin.android, parse-platform

I am porting my WP8 app to Android using Xamarin. I use Parse as a data back end. I got an array of ints that I want to save into Parse. Parse's API has a Put() method that only accepts Java.Lang.Object. I cant figure how to convert my .Net int array to Java.Lang.Object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple helper class:

```
public class JavaObject<T> : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public JavaObject (T obj)
    {
        this.Value = obj;
    }

    public T Value { get; private set; }
}
```

If that doesn't work with Parse then you could probably just create an ArrayList which is a Java object.

Comment: This will not work with arrays (e.g. `Java.Lang.Float[][][] -> Java.Lang.Object`)